# Customize Output Table to Include Missing Variable

Tags: excel, sas

I have an excel file with sheets that contain both the table shells (including formulas) and the raw data output from SAS (eg. Sheet 1 = Table Shell; Sheet 2 = Table 1 Data).

I am trying to update the table data without having to re-do the table shells and corresponding formulas. However, for the time series I have 6 participant groups, but one did not report data this cycle. The problem is that the missing group is sandwiched in the middle, and I can not paste the SAS output to the excel sheets. I want to output that missing group in the results but as blank counts and percents.

Right now I am doing pretty standard `proc freq table var*Group/ norow nocol` to get the count and total percent.

```
    Group 1 | Group 2 | ... | Missing Group | Group 5 | Group 6
N    500         303                           475        630
%
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `PROC FREQ` can do an entirely missing column, unfortunately.  `PROC TABULATE` can, as can most procedures that have a CLASS variable, using `preloadfmt` on the `class` statement and `printmiss` to tell it to create all logical groupings (which can be dangerous, so use it with caution on complicated tables).

```
proc format;
value $genderf
'M'='Male'
'F'='Female'
'T'='Trans'
;
quit;
proc tabulate data=sashelp.class;
class sex/preloadfmt;
var height;
format sex $genderf.;
tables sex,height*mean/printmiss;
run;
```

The only real way to make it work in `PROC FREQ` is to either postprocess the data (if you're looking for a dataset rather than a printed output), or to add a dummy row for your missing time period, which would of course alter your results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think this may be out of my reach at the moment. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: Actually a simple PROC TABULATE wouldn't be hard at all to suggest if you post your complete code and a sample data set.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. Actually, I realized that once I export to excel, I can simply insert a new column, which solves the problem. I just need to standardize the output order.